# Css Media Object Source Order

Tags: css, oocss

I love the idea behind using a media object module as described here:

http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/

It's css that can apply to lots of HTML patterns and has the big advantage that it doesn't matter how big the image is or how big the container is that the module is contained in.

The problem is that it relies on the media (eg the image) coming first in the source like this

```
    IMAGE
    STARTCONTENTDIV
    ENDCONTENTDIV
```

This becomes a semantic issue when within that content div you might have a heading like this:

```
    IMAGE
    STARTCONTENTDIV
      H1
      DESCRIPTION
    ENDCONTENTDIV
```

This way the h1 is after the image even though it should be before so the document outline makes sense. It should be like this:

```
    STARTCONTENTDIV
      H1
      DESCRIPTION
    ENDCONTENTDIV
    IMAGE
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this in a liquid layout container, when we don't know the widths of either the image or the content div?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox allows you to rearrange content without knowing how wide the elements are.  The down side is that support for it is poor (IE10+, Opera, Chrome; the current Firefox follows an older spec, but could do this layout).

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
    <h1>Title Here</h1>

    <p>Paragraph o' text</p>
  </div>

  <img class="child" />
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
}

div.child {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  order: 2;
}

img.child {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  order: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CNWGn/ (prefixes not included)

Comment: This answer is really useful - I do appreciate it and flexbox is something I'll look into one day! ... but I should really have said that I was looking for something more cross browser. The OOCSS media object works in ie6 so I'm hoping for something that also does this. I have a feeling that nothing will. I think you'll at least need to know the width of one of them.

Comment: There's nothing special about the "OOCSS media object": it uses style properties that have been around forever.  The only other way to rearrange content the way you want is through absolute positioning, which is typically not flexible and does require knowing the dimensions of the image.

Comment: I guess I was just hoping that someone else would have used the technique and thought of a way of making it less source dependent. I suppose the question was a bit misleading in that sense. Would love to be able to float something to the left of things that come after it in the source code without knowing any of the dimensions but will have to wait... thanks again anyway